# Is there a simple way to describe all $O(n)$ algorithms given simple assumptions about the machine?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

For example, can all $O(n)$ algorithms (where $n$ is strictly an integer) be described as:

```
for k in 0..f(n):
   O(1)(k)
```

where $f$ is a linear polynomial in $\Bbb{Z}[n]$ is included in the description,

and where $O(1)(k)$ above simply means some $O(1)$ operation that might reference the variable $k$.
?

Thanks.

Comment: no. there are many $\mathcal{O}(n)$ recursive algorithms, and there are also many $\mathcal{O}(n)$ algorithms taking $C n+ B$ operations where $C > 10^{10^{10}}$ so no 3 lines won't be enough

Comment: @user1952009 you didn't mention any good news.